# Magento CE 1.9.0.1 robots.txt not showing when called

Tags: magento, windows-ce, robots.txt

If I put a robots.txt in public_html (permissions 755) and try to see it in my browser by websitename/robots.txt I get an error from magento: The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

CE 1.9.0.1 The rest of the site works fine. robots.txt file only has the following in it (for now):

User-Agent: *

Disallow:

Drives me crazy.

Where do I put the robots.txt or am I doing something else wrong?

the website is www.holiseeds.com if you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your robots.txt. Clear your browser's cache and remove all cookies.

Comment: Fixed. (I feel really really stupid now!) Thank you.